# Compare values in 2 object arrays and create new array, js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays:

```
blockedNumbers: ['123', '456', '789', '247'];
contacts: [
           {name: 'Foo', numbers: [{ home:'123' }, { mobile:'456' }]}, 
           {name: 'Bar', numbers: [{ home:'789' }]}
          ]
```

I want to create a new array of blocked contacts which will contain:

```
[
  { name: Foo, numbers: [{ home:'123' }, { mobile:'456' }] }, 
  {name: 'Bar', numbers: [{ home:'789' }]} 
  '247'
]
```

So the solution I have tried first loops over blocked numbers, then forEach contact, if blocked number in numbers, push to array. But the result turns out as

```
[
  '123'
  { name: Foo, numbers: ['123', '456'] }, 
  {name: 'Bar', numbers: ['789']} 
  '456'
  '789'
  '247'
]
```

Code below:

```
const newBlacklistWithContacts = [];
blockedNumbers.forEach((blockedNumber) => {
    contacts.map((contact) => {
    // if blocked number in contacts
    Object.keys(contact.numbers).forEach((e) => {
    if (contact.numbers[e] === blockedNumber) {
        const alreadyAdded = newBlacklistWithContacts.find(blacklistContact => blacklistContact.name === contact.name);
        if (!alreadyAdded) {
            return newBlacklistWithContacts.push({ name: contact.name, numbers: contact.numbers });
        }
    }
    else if (!newBlacklistWithContacts.includes(blockedNumber)) {
        return newBlacklistWithContacts.push(blockedNumber);
    }
    });
    });
});
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this & actually return what I need? (All of the blacklisted contacts and if not in contacts, only the number) I am using js and React.js in this project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data set is really large, you can optimise your algorithm by doing *O(1)* lookups in a `Set` instead of using `indexOf` or `includes` which do *O(n)* lookups:

```js
// Input
const blockedNumbers =  ['123', '456', '789', '247'];
const contacts = [{name: 'Foo', numbers: [{ home:'123' }, { mobile:'456' }]}, {name: 'Bar', numbers: [{ home:'789' }]}];

// Algorithm
const set = new Set(blockedNumbers);
const notused = new Set(blockedNumbers);
const newBlacklistWithContacts = contacts.filter(contact => 
    contact.numbers.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[0])
                   .filter(number => set.has(number) && (notused.delete(number) || true)).length
).concat(...notused);

// Output
console.log(newBlacklistWithContacts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var blockedNumbers = ['123', '456', '789', '247'];
var contacts = [{
        name: 'Foo',
        numbers: [{
            home: '123'
        }, {
            mobile: '456'
        }]
    },
    {
        name: 'Bar',
        numbers: [{
            home: '789'
        }]
    }
]

var blocks = [];
contacts.forEach(v1 => (v1.numbers.forEach(v2 => {
    blocks.push(Object.values(v2)[0]);
})));
blockedNumbers.forEach(val => (blocks.indexOf(val) == -1 ? contacts.push(val) : null));

console.log(contacts);
```

Comment: Two issues: (1) This mutates the input. (2) This always includes all contacts, not just the blacklisted.